# QtRO - class qremoteobjects - how can connect 2 and more remote peers beetwen TCP

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp, qurl

I was build example simpleswitch with registry node in Qt5.9. It's work fine, but when i replace *QUrl("local.registry")* and *QUrl("local.replica")* in definition **QRemoteObjectRegistryHost** and **QRemoteObjectHost** to *QUrl("tcp://localhost:9999")* or *"tcp://127.0.0.1:9999"*, or paste current host address to defniton... i have error after run app...

> qt.remoteobjects:  Listen failed for URL: QUrl("tcp://127.0.0.1:9999")
>
> qt.remoteobjects:  QAbstractSocket::AddressInUseError
>
> qt.remoteobjects:  Could not create ClientIoDevice for client. Invalid url/scheme provided? QUrl("")

Answer (score 2):

The valid value, use instead of `QUrl("local.registry")`:

```
QUrl("tcp://192.168.0.3:-1");
```

The valid value, use instead of `QUrl("local.replica")`:

```
QUrl("tcp://192.168.0.3:9999");
```

The IP address *192.168.0.3* - used for example (it value valid for my workstation in our office network) in your case IP address can contain other digits.

Answer (score 0):

If Qt is indicating that 'the address is in use' then that is likely the source of the problem, literally the socket at IP:PORT is being used. You may check your development environment to see if you have multiple processes running of the same app - this is often the case and it leads to a collision of address spaces. We see this error in our environment consistently, and the root cause is simply as stated: 'the address is in use'.